# snowflake: what does copy grants in this statement do

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql statement as below

```
create or replace view 
SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_VIEW_NAME copy grants as select * from 
SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_VIEW_NAME;
```

And currently i done hate the view `VIEW_NAME` in the schema `SOME_SCHEMA_NAME`

The above command fails

```
SQL compilation error: Object 'SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_VIEW_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.
```

I am not sure what `copy grants as select * from SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_VIEW_NAME` also

also why its failing `'SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_VIEW_NAME' does not exist` because `create or replace`  is what we are using

Comment: You can’t have a view that references itself. How would that make sense, a view selecting from itself?

Comment: Copy grants just replicates the permissions and inherits any explicit access privileges on the original object. The error is because you are creating a view from the same view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have received is due to a lack of the required privileges.

However, you could not create it, as the View definition refers to a view being defined.

If you have the required privileges, you will receive an error "View definition refers to view being defined: "